# Lubuntu installation not booting up

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I made a fresh Lubuntu installation and the whole installation process was complete with 0 errors, but the moment that boots up it goes perfect until the Lubuntu logo then it just stays blank and it seems (in  my experience) that is like I did not install the system and it`s impossible!

Comment: Can you access a TTY via Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: No i can`t  ..-.

Comment: Trying to install  Lubuntu again and see what happens , but another question will be its there a limitation for the hard drive capacity installation ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking if there will be any limit to the size of the hard drive?

Comment: I can access Tty . Now what I do

Comment: So you've reinstalled, but the problem is still there?

Comment: Yes The pproblem is still there